# How to display the number of messages received in only in the receiver's main activity?

Tags: android-studio, parse-platform, sinch

I followed this tutorial https://www.sinch.com/learn/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/ and it worked fine, but I need to display the number of messages sent only on the receiver's main activity so that when the receiver opens the app he/she will see "You have #number messages", can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Can you explain more, what its the problem?

Comment: I used the sinch instant messaging service and I can send messages between two devices, but I need to display the number of messages received so whenever a user receives a certain number of messages it will appear in the application's home page as "you have #number messages"

Comment: I assume you save them in localstorage, just count em there